# PostgreSQL query won't finish on StandBY server

Tags: database, postgresql, query-optimization

We have a Primary-Stanby setup on PostgreSQL 12.1. A DELETE query is run on the primary server (which takes time but finishes completely) however the same query does not finish (and runs like forever):

```
DELETE FROM EVENTS
WHERE Event_Type_ID != 2
AND last_update_time <= '2020-11-04'
AND Event_ID NOT IN ( SELECT DISTINCT Event_ID FROM Event_Association )
AND Event_ID NOT IN ( SELECT DISTINCT Event_ID FROM EVENTS WHERE Last_Update_Time > '2020-11-14');
```

The execution plan is as follows (replacing delete with select query for the same):
https://explain.depesz.com/s/GZp7

There is a INDEX created on EVENTS.Event_ID and Event_Association.Event_ID however the delete query still won't finish on the standby server.
The EVENTS table has more than 2 million rows and the Event_Association table has more than 300,000 rows.

Can someone help me resolve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Just to bring out some possibly helpful information, to you knowledge, could there be other processes running on the alternate server when the delete is happening?

Comment: Yes, there are other processes running on the standby server. Almost similar processes which are running on the Primary server (on which this delete query takes time but finishes)

Comment: What are usually called standby servers are read only (to users), and the delete would immediately throw an error without even starting execution.  Please describe you set up more completely.

Comment: This Delete query is actually run on the Primary server... The Stand by server gets this query from the Primary server. This query is not being executed by a User but coming from the Primary server as a part of replication